# How to disable checkstyle in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

I have checkstyle plugin installed in my Eclipse. 
How do I disable it for a specific project in my workspace?

If that is not feasible I would like to turn off checkstyle.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can also disable Checkstyle just on one project by the contextual menu at the project level.

See:

[image: Desactivate Checkstyle]

If you really need to uninstall the plugin, it is best to use:

```
Help/About/Installation Details
```

Select the right plugins and uninstall them:

[image: Uninstall Plugins]

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured this out myself. Just need to remove the folder "com.atlassw.tools.eclipse.checkstyle_4.4.1" under the plugins folder of eclipse. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

In latest eclipse version(9/2014) we have to visit **Help -> Eclipse Market** and go to installed tab. Then select uninstall. After uninstallation this will ask for a eclipse restart. And that is it.

[image]